# Permanent youtube live chat web embed?

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed

I have tried this in the past and failed, reaching out to SO for some peer review.

I am able to embed my youtube livestream chat using the following:

`<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=MIky1vb3Tds&embed_domain=justdalek.com"width="100%" height="700"></iframe>`

That said, the way youtube works, as soon as my livestream ends, so does the use of that video ID `MIky1vb3Tds` and I have to generate a new one in live studio, then update my web embed, every single time.

I have been seeking a way to make a more permanent embed without luck so far

I found another thread where it was recommended that the person try something like

`<iframe width="350px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?channel=UCeTQOO2-MerayKuv3k12hMg&embed_domain=justdalek.com"></iframe>`

But this fails, a frame loads with a monkey saying something went wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas/experience with a permanent web embed that just works off your latest livestream?